# my .htaccess file is not working (RewriteRule) on wamp but working on production environment

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wamp

This is the content of my .htaccess file:

```
# Use PHP5 Single php.ini as default
#AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5s .php

RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^about.html$ index.php?action=about
RewriteRule ^audioCats.html$ index.php?action=viewCat&catId=0&type=audio
RewriteRule ^videoCats.html$ index.php?action=viewCat&catId=0&type=video
RewriteRule ^audioCat_([0-9]+).html$ index.php?action=viewCat&catId=$1&type=audio
RewriteRule ^videoCat_([0-9]+).html$ index.php?action=viewCat&catId=$1&type=video
RewriteRule ^blog.html$ index.php?action=viewCat&catId=0&type=blog&pageId=0
RewriteRule ^blog_([0-9]+).html$ index.php?action=blog&id=$1
#RewriteRule ^blog_([0-9]+).html$ index.php?action=viewCat&catId=0&type=blog&pageId=0
RewriteRule ^blogCat_([0-9]+).html$ index.php?action=viewCat&catId=$1&type=blog&pageId=0
RewriteRule ^blogCat_([0-9]+)_([0-9]+).html$ index.    php?action=viewCat&catId=$1&type=blog&pageId=$2
RewriteRule ^articlesCat_([0-9]+).html$ index.    php?action=viewCat&catId=$1&type=articles&pageId=0
RewriteRule ^articlesCat_([0-9]+)_([0-9]+).html$ index.    php?action=viewCat&catId=$1&type=articles&pageId=$2
RewriteRule ^articles_([0-9]+).html$ index.php?action=articles&id=$1


RewriteRule ^(.*)Rating.html$ index.php?action=rateIt&itemType=$1

RewriteRule ^videoRating.html$ index.php?action=rateIt&itemType=video
RewriteRule ^video([0-9]+).html$ index.php?action=video&id=$1
RewriteRule ^audio([0-9]+).html$ index.php?action=audio&id=$1
RewriteRule ^eps([0-9]+).html$ index.php?action=eps&id=$1

RewriteRule ^logActivity.html$ index.php?action=logActivity
RewriteRule ^search.html$ index.php?action=search

#Comments
RewriteRule ^addComment.html$ index.php?action=addComment
RewriteRule ^voteForComment.html$ index.php?action=voteForComment
RewriteRule ^fetchComment.html$ index.php?action=fetchComment
RewriteRule ^moreComments.html$ index.php?action=fetchMoreComments
#End Comments
RewriteRule ^fetchVideoUrl.html$ index.php?action=fetchVideoUrl
RewriteRule ^register.html$ index.php?action=register
RewriteRule ^editAccount.html$ index.php?action=editAccount
RewriteRule ^login.html$ index.php?action=login
RewriteRule ^ajaxLogin.html$ index.php?action=login&ajax=true
RewriteRule ^inbox.html$ index.php?action=inbox
RewriteRule ^sendSeries.html$ index.php?action=sendSeries&catId=0
RewriteRule ^logout.html$ index.php?action=logout
RewriteRule ^profile.html$ index.php?action=profile
RewriteRule ^profile([0-9]+).html$ index.php?action=profile&userId=$1
RewriteRule ^sendMessage([0-9]+).html$ index.php?action=sendMessage&userId=$1
RewriteRule ^friendRequest([0-9]+).html$ index.php?action=friendRequest&userId=$1
RewriteRule ^friendApprove([0-9]+).html$ index.php?action=friendApprove&userId=$1
RewriteRule ^friendDeny([0-9]+).html$ index.php?action=friendDeny&userId=$1
RewriteRule ^updateAudioListen.html$ index.php?action=updateAudioListen
RewriteRule ^downloads/([0-9]+)/(.*)/?$ index.php?action=download&id=$1&hash=$2
RewriteRule ^vote.html$ index.php?action=vote
RewriteRule ^contact.html$ index.php?action=contact
RewriteRule ^mailList.html$ index.php?action=maillist
RewriteRule ^friendRequests.html$ index.php?action=friendRequests
RewriteRule ^index.html$ index.php
RewriteRule ^rss$ index.php?action=rss
RewriteRule ^rss/(.*)$ index.php?action=rss&keyword=$1
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?action=sitemap

RewriteRule ^cartoon.html$ index.php?action=cartoon&pageId=0
RewriteRule ^cartoon_page_([0-9]+).html$ index.php?action=cartoon&pageId=$1
RewriteRule ^cartoon_([0-9]+).html$ index.php?action=cartoon&id=$1

RewriteRule ^colors.css$ css.php

RewriteRule ^deleteMessage_([0-9]+).html$ index.php?action=deleteMessage&id=$1
RewriteRule ^readMessage_([0-9]+).html$ index.php?action=readMessage&id=$1
RewriteRule ^monitorMessage_([0-9]+).html$ index.php?action=monitoringMessage&lastCount=$1
```

when I -for example -go to localhost/qtoon/contact.html it gives 404 (redirects me to wamp's home page) but when I go to localhost/qtoon/index.php?action=contact it works ..

The problem does not exist on the production environment (I mean on the online hosting server)

Comment: `mysite/contact.html` != `^contact.html` ?

Comment: He means that going to localhost/contact.html is not caught by the regular expression ^contact.html. I'm not sure if this is the case, though, are you sure `mod_rewrite` is enabled in your Apache config?

Comment: Enable your `RewriteLog` and you'll see what I mean, it's a good tool to debug this. Specifically that going to http://localhost/ **/mysite/** contact.html does not match ^contact.html.

Comment: @Wrikken Nevermind, I just spotted it. I assumed you used `mysite` as a `example.com` replacement, but I was wrong.

Comment: Why maintain such an onerous .htaccess file when it seems you are pretty much just rewriting to front controller (index.php) anyway?  Why not just remove most of the stuff in favor of code which inspects the URI and does appropriate action (more like a proper router function)?

Comment: "mysite" is an example of the name of the project folder in the www folder in wamp.

Comment: no it is in the site root folder

Comment: You wrote about `localhost/exampleProj/contact.html` URL giving 404? What exactly is your DocumentRoot value and is this .htaccess in `DocumentRoot` OR in `DocumentRoot/exampleProj/`?

Comment: The site folder is called qtoon and that htaccess file is located in the root folder of the site which is qtoon

Comment: just an example for the folder name ..

Comment: [Let's discuss this in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65652/discussion-between-anubhava-and-hazemtaha)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rules appear to be correct but `RewriteBase` seems to be the problem since your .htaccess is residing in a sub-directory.

Use this `RewriteBase` instead:

```
RewriteBase /qtoon/
```

Answer (score 0):

The 404 looks like a combination of `RewriteBase /` and working within a subdirectory of the domain (i.e `http://localhost/exampleProj/`).

This is because the `/` will force apache to rewrite the request to `http://localhost/index.php`.

The solution would be to remove `RewriteBase /` or set up a virtual host. You can set up a virtual host in the Apache config files and /etc/hosts file (I believe it's in the system folder under drivers\etc on Windows).

An example of a virtual host configuration:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html#twoips